# Will Chrome 66 new auto play policy affect audio tag?

Tags: google-chrome, html5-audio

I have some applications which rely on the audio tag auto play... Will the new chrome's policy affect it?

Comment: Yes, user's interaction needed. More info can be found at https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does. In Chrome 66 sound can only be played back after a user interaction.
See the post on the Google developer blog: [Autoplay Policy Changes](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes).

**Edit:**
Because this change broke a lot of existing websites Chrome rolled back the autoplay change, it will be reimplemented in a later version of Chrome to give developers more time to fix their code. See [Google partially rolls back Chrome 66's autoplay changes](https://www.androidpolice.com/2018/05/15/google-partially-rolls-back-chrome-66s-autoplay-changes/)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to allow audio to a whitelist of sites on Chrome 77. You can do that by:

1. Open the site which you want to whitelist on Chrome.
2. Click on the SSL/Padlock icon before the URL.
3. Choose Site Settings.
4. Scroll down to permissions & look for sound.
5. Change the value from Automatic too allowed.
6. Reload & check.

Tested on Chrome 77 on OSX.